# filter data with angular

Tags: angular, firebase

when I create a publication, select a category. Later in a different page, I show all the categories, but I need to show only the categories that contain publications.

in ruby ​​on rails would be something like that

```
- if category.posts
   #show
```

json of categories data

```
[{"Cortes":{"name":"Cortes"}, "peinados":{"name":"peinados"}}]
```

json of posts data

```
[{"category": "Cortes","title": "first"}]
```

in this case only the category Cortes contains a publication, I need the other does not show because there are no publications with that category.
**in this way I show the categories:**

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
      {{ category.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.filter to this as follows,

```
this.categories = category.posts.filter(cat=>cat.publication != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

solve it like this

```
filter (category) {
       const x = this.publicaciones.filter(post => post.category === category);
       return x.length;
    }

    getCategory(services, name) {
        const s = [];
        Object.values(services).forEach(key => {
          if(key.img) {
            if (this.filterC(key.name) >= 1) {
              s.push({ name: key.name, img: key.img });
            }
          }
        });
        this.check = s;
      }
```